# Unable to install CouchDB on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, apt-get

I am trying to install CouchDB on Ubuntu 17.10.  I get the following error message when using apt-get:

```
 sudo apt-get install couchdb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 couchdb : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
           Recommends: python-progressbar but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After installing it via snap and trying to start the database, I still get error messages:

```
sudo -i -u couchdb couchdb/bin/couchdb
sudo: unable to change directory to /var/lib/couchdb: No such file or directory
sudo: unable to execute /bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

Instructions for starting taken from

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/install/unix.html

Comment: You can try snap install [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/install/snap.html)

Comment: @bamanow  It looks like the install with snap was successful, but I still can't start the db or verify that it was successfully installed.  Please see my updated question.

Comment: @bamanow  nvm, it works now

Comment: Glad that this was useful

Comment: I get similar problems when trying to upgrade couchdb from v2.1.1 to v2.3.1. Very frustrating